# How to find the commit hash that introduced a given tree?

Tags: git

I have a broken tree with the hash given by

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
warning in tree <tree-hash>: nullSha1: contains entries pointing to null sha1
```

and I want to find the commit that introduced it. 
I know I can find that info if I try to filter the branch with, e.g.:

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <my_broken_subdir>' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
...
Rewrite <commit_hash> error:
    cache entry has null sha1: <my_broken_subdir>
```

However, I have a long history project and running `git-filter` would take too long.

> UPDATE

Actually, the tree is broken by that it contains a null sha1. Therefore, `git bisect` won't work, since in any commit I check out, running

```
 git fsck
```

would always give me the

```
warning in tree <tree-hash>: nullSha1: contains entries pointing to null sha1
```

Comment: Maybe something with `git bisect`? That'd at least get you to log N commits to check. Somebody more clever than I could probably give you a useful example.

Answer (score 1):

In general, trying to find a tree via the commits doesn't sound like fun, since the "broken" `TREE` could be anywhere in the `TREE` hierarchy of any given commit.  It sounds like maybe you know the corresponding directory path, which would simplify things a little, but that still sounds like a pretty involved bit of custom scripting.

It might be simpler to use `git bisect`, with `git fsck` (looking for the error) as your test for each commit.